# Joomla ignoring upload_max_filesize and own upload size config

Tags: php, joomla

I've got a user of our Joomla system having issues uploading a file. The file is around 12Megs in size. If I log into the Joomla backend and then select Content->Media Manager, I can upload this file, no problem. The options in Media Manager are set to allow up to 15M files. PHP.ini has been edited with the following:

post_max_size = 20M

upload_max_filesize = 15M

However, if I log out of the admin screens, and use the standard login module on the front page, I have the same issue the user is having. Navigate to the page I want to add the link, click the edit button to edit the content, highlight the text to link and click the link button. Click the "Browse" button and then the Upload button to get small window you drag your file to. I drag over a 12M file and I get an error saying it exceeds an 8M file limitation.
[image: 8M file limitation???]

Since editing the php.ini I have restarted the web service, but it doesn't seem to have had an effect. I'm not sure where it's getting this 8M limitation from. Any ideas?

Some info that may (or may not) be of assistance:

Server: IIS on Windows Server 2008R2

Joomla Version: 2.5.11

PHP Version: 5.3.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bypassing the fact that you are still on Joomla 2.5.11, therefore a perfect candidate for being hacked, you might want to look at your Content Editor settings for upload limits (is it JCE?).

Also keep in mind that there is [Joomla Stack Exchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) for all Joomla related questions.

Comment: Thanks much, found the offending 8Mb parameter in the JCE Editor Profile under components. 

And thanks for the pointer to the Joomla Stack Exchange site. Didn't know that existed!